# Headless chrome doesnt work on centos with same python selenium code after 1year

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

The same python selenium code to automate some functionality works fine till 1 to 1.5 years and suddenly stopped at a point

**Puesdocode:**

1. The website is https website and need to authenticate the user.
2. There are files which needs to be downloaded. (Maximum of 30 files in page)
3. once downloaded all the files from page move to another page (At the bottom of page < pageno >, can be seen).
4. As per step "<",">", these are the image icons. **The problem comes here.**

I can see that the icons are available and could find the web element and when "click()", i get an error

```
nextPageControl.click()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: headless chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
```

or the script hangs there indefinitely as page load didn't happen

Nothing seems to work, can find the chrome and webdriver version in the log

Comment: **Tried Following Solutions**
1. Added in the chrome options
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
    options.add_argument('--lang=en-GB')
    driver.set_window_size(1400, 600)

2.     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", nextPageControl)

Comment: Your issue is in `Command.CLICK_ELEMENT`. Update the question with relevant HTML, your code trials and text based complete error stack trace.

Comment: Check your Chrome and ChromeDriver versions. The major version numbers need to match and chrome likes to auto-update.

Comment: Found partial solution, after executing the same script on windows 8 machine on chrome browser 79.0.3945.130, it works fine. So i had upgraded the browser version to 79.0.3945.130 in Centos linux machine. Now the same script is not able to load a page.

Comment: I am actually trying to automate download of files from Sharepoint. Script works fine till login but after clicking the folder which has files intended to be downloaded, this particular folder is not able load the webpage may be because the specific folder has huge amount files could be around 60000 files. As i said in my previous comment that now it works fine in the win 8 chrome latest version after setting the set_page_load_time(600). The same code doesnt work on the centos linux with same browser version. Any solution would be really helpful.